# x86/x64 instruction PCLMULQDQ (Carry-Less Multiplication Quadword)

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, machine-code

This instruction is on page 1067 of the Intel x64 manual but it doesn't say if it multiplies unsigned or signed integers.

Anyone know?

Comment: in case of non-widening multiplications like 32x32 → 32, there's also no difference in signed or unsigned because the result will always be the same

Comment: for this instruction you can read [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-carry-less-multiplication-instruction-and-its-usage-for-computing-the-gcm-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. As the label on the tin says it's a *carry-less* multiplication, not an unsigned or signed multiplication. The operands are treated as elements of a [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), not as integers.